# Use of preposition "at"

Tags: prepositions

Could you take a look at the sentence below?

Doesn't everyone deserve a chance **at** a good life?

This is a title of one of TED speeches. In this sentence, can we use "to" instead of "at"?

What is the difference in meaning, and which preposition is more appropriate?

Comment: Looks like a typo for "a *chance* at a good life" not a *change*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title of the Ted Talk is [Doesn't everyone deserve a chan**c**e at a good life?](https://www.ted.com/talks/jim_yong_kim_doesn_t_everyone_deserve_a_chance_at_a_good_life), not chan**g**e.

Answer (score 2):

"To" doesn't make sense; "at" is correct.

I note that the original question had "change" instead of "chance", and that might have caused the OP's confusion. I further note that with the correction to "chance", this is a valid question.

Comment: With *chance*, another possibility would e *of* - *a chance of a good life* - but not *to*, which would work with *change*.